# Proving/Disproving $M$ has the structure of an $R$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, big-list

Given an abelian group $M$ and a ring $R$, how can one prove or disprove that $M$ has the structure of an $R$-module? When proving $M$ is an $R$-module, if it is not obvious how to define an action $R\times M\to M$ that satisfies the module axioms, what theorems/techniques can be used to test if $M$ is an $R$-module?

What techniques can be applied to show $M$ is not an $R$-module?

For instance, how would I test if $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module?

All examples, nonexamples, links, and theorems (that can be ingested by someone familiar with Dummit/Foote) are welcome!

Comment: If there's no action  then it's not a module.  If you don't have the action then it doesn't make sense to even ask if something *is* an $R$ module.  What you probably mean is can we define an action so that something can be turned into an $R$ module.

Comment: Hi Gregory, sometimes it's obvious how to construct the action, but what if it is not so obvious? On the other hand, how do I prove the non-existence of an action if $M$ doesn't have a module structure?

Comment: @cap: are you interested in general techniques only, or in the particular example you listed as well? I don't have much in the way of the former, but I do have an answer for the latter.

Comment: When you say set, do you really mean something like abelian group? Because the only structure a set really has is its cardinality. There are the obvious facts about cardinality, like that a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-module must have cardinality a power of 2, but probably not a lot of interesting stuff when you move to infinite sets. (I could be wrong about that, though.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim General techniques would be appreciated, but I'd also like to see your answer to the latter.

Comment: @JakobHansen Yes, $M$ an abelian group.

Comment: If you don't mind degenerate actions (i.e., nonunitary actions), every Abelian group $A$ is a left $R$-module for any ring (possibly nonunital) by the assignment $ra := 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A structure of (unitary left) $R$-module over an abelian group $G$ (written additively) is determined by a (unitary) ring homomorphism $R\to\operatorname{End}(G)$, where $\operatorname{End}(G)$ consists of the endomorphisms of $G$ under the standard sum operation and map composition.

To see why, suppose $G$ is an $R$-module. For $r\in R$, define $\lambda_r\colon G\to G$ by $\lambda_r(x)=rx$. It is easy to verify that $\lambda_r\in\operatorname{End}(G)$ and that the map $\lambda\colon R\to\operatorname{End}(G)$ is indeed a ring homomorphism.

Conversely, give a ring homomorphism $\varphi\colon R\to\operatorname{End}(G)$, define, for $r\in R$ and $x\in G$,
$$
rx=\varphi(r)(x)
$$
(the endomorphism $\varphi(r)$ evaluated at $x$). Again, it is easy to verify this gives $G$ a structure of $R$-modules.

Also easy is to see that doing the two steps in sequence takes back to the starting point: an $R$-module structure defines a ring homomorphism which in turn defines the same $R$-module structure and conversely.

In order to see whether $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ can be given a structure of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module, we need to find a ring homomorphism as above. The task is made easier by the observation that $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. If $f\in\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, we see that $f(x)=f(1)x$ (multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$).

A ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[i]\to\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is determined uniquely by a ring homomorphism $\psi\colon\mathbb{Z}[X]\to\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\ker\psi\supseteq\langle X^2+1\rangle$, by definition of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Such a $\psi$ is determined once we fix $t=\psi(X)$. Such an element must satisfy $t^2+1=0$, which means $t=2$ or $t=3$.

Thus there are two module structures on $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$. One is
$$
(a+bi)[x]=[ax+2bx]
$$
and the other one is
$$
(a+bi)[x]=[ax+3bx]
$$
as it turns out once we explicit the computations.

Can we find a structure of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module on $\mathbb{Q}$? No, because $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Q}$ and there's no rational number whose square is $-1$.

Neither we can find one on $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, for a similar reason.

The general problem is much harder: here we could use knowledge of how $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ can be obtained as a quotient ring of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and also of the endomorphism ring of the abelian group. However, endomorphism rings of abelian group are quite difficult to study and so are ring homomorphisms.

Comment: So to summarize, in this case a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module structure on $M$ is equivalent to an abelian group structure on $M$, along with an endomorphism of the abelian group $M$ whose square (i.e. composition with itself) is equal to the negation operation.  And from another point of view, since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD and therefore a PID, any finitely generated module over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of finitely many copies of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ or its quotients.  e.g. $\mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z}$ with the "map $i$ to 2" structure is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[i] / (2-i)$.

Comment: "Can we find a structure of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module on $\mathbb{Q}$?"  Needs to specify the compatibility with the normal abelian group structure of $\mathbb{Q}$ to get the "no" answer.  Otherwise, since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ itself is countable, it's bijective with $\mathbb{Q}$, so you could transfer the canonical $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module structure of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ to define a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module structure on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler The abelian group structure is considered given, otherwise the question would make little sense, except when the underlying set is finite, for a countable ring.

Answer (score 1):

In the particular example you gave, in fact you can make $\mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z}$ into a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-algebra by "mapping $i$ to 2" -- the specific formula for module multiplication would be:
$$ (a+bi) \cdot c := (a+2b)c $$
for $a+bi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, $c \in \mathbb{Z} / 5 \mathbb{Z}$.  (Here, the essential property of 2 which will make $\alpha \cdot (\beta \cdot x) = (\alpha \beta) \cdot x$ work is that $2^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{5}$.)

For a possible technique for a negative proof, we'll prove $\mathbb{Z} / 7 \mathbb{Z}$ cannot be made into a $\mathbb{Z}[i]$-module in a way compatible with its usual abelian group structure.  So, suppose it could be.  Then consider the induced action of the multiplicative group $\{ \pm 1, \pm i \}$ on the module.  Each orbit is of size either 1, 2, or 4.  However, the only possible orbit of size 1 (or fixed point) is $\{ 0 \}$ since if $x$ is a fixed point, then $x = -x$ so $x = 0$.  On the other hand, an orbit size of exactly 2 is impossible: that would imply for a generator $x$ that $-x = i^2 x = x$ which again implies $x = 0$ so it's actually a fixed point.  Therefore, we would get a decomposition of $\mathbb{Z} / 7 \mathbb{Z}$ into a single orbit of size 1 and then orbits of size 4, which is clearly impossible.